# Need to restrict Parent account in Community user

Tags: community, customer-community, partner-communities, partner-portal

Created Account "Test Acc" With contact " Test Cont" enabled the Account as partner and enabled the contact as Partner user.
Logged in as community user "Test Cont" and viewed the Parent Account, I am able to view the "Test Acc" in Community page.
Actually "Test Acc" it will not display in community.

OWD settings :
Account (Default External Access) = **Private**

Is this standard functionality,Parent Account visible in community when logged in as Partner User?
Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is Standard functionality. When you set OWD to private user can only view there current Account record and not any other record.

You will need to put extra check to hide record from user (Which include a middle page which check current user profile and based on that redirect to detail page or show error message.)